# Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel

Tags: java, android

I got a error when running tests in my app in Android platform:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel.
at android.view.InputChannel.nativeReadFromParcel(Native Method)
at android.view.InputChannel.readFromParcel(InputChannel.java:135)
at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.add(IWindowSession.java:523)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:481)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:301)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2507)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1986)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:803)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:570)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don`t known but I think it can be a error in Android platform? What do you think it can be?

Comment: This crash is ambiguous, we should allow this to be discussed.

Comment: It's bug in Android: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=32470

Comment: This question should be open.

Answer (score 4):

This sometimes occurs when I open, exit and re-open an app. The issue I have is that I forgot to run cleanup on the SoundManager:

```
public static void cleanup() {
     mSoundPool.release();
     mSoundPool = null;
     mSoundPoolMap.clear();
    mAudioManager.unloadSoundEffects();
    _instance = null;
}
```

You must have something still running in memory that you have now run twice.

Answer (score 2):

This exception coming may be because of, for reading data from filediscriptor process is different as that file was open through another process.If different processs try to read filediscriptor  that belongs to another process,then while reading it will throw exception.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can one make sure that its done from the same process?

Comment: Actually there is no certain way to make sure until you are only, who doing that all operations with file(means from opening to reading data). While opening the file first time,you need to maintain process id and at the time of reading,get the current running process,then cross check it.